# How to setup iframe for iPad?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a question about the iframe issue in iPad.
I am using Bootstrap modal to embed an iframe inside the modal. Everything looks great on all desktop browser. However, the content in iframe is over extended in iPad portrait mode. I am not sure if it's the Bootstrap issue. Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5eq9s4t/3/).

```
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">
        Click to open modal
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="test">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe id="iframe1" style="height:600px; width:100%;" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [Media queries?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the responsive embed component with Bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/tesuye/1/edit**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is the CSS used to make both aspect ratio choices (16by9 or 4by3). You can make other aspect ratios by using this format (don't change these):

```
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-4by3 {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

*Your own:*

```
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-myAspectRatio {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}
```